# Angular and Material Design Router Outlets

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm working on this Angular application using Material Design and I need to have 2 side drawers, on each side. However, one of them is to have an router-outlet on it.

I can't get it to work and I think it's because I'm trying to load it from within another router-Outlet.

Here is what I got:

### SideNavComponent.html

```html
<mat-drawer-container class="container">
    <app-header (openMenu)="drawer.toggle()"></app-header>
    <mat-drawer #drawer class="sidenav" mode="over">
        <mat-selection-list #shoes [multiple]="false">
            <mat-list-option i18n="menu.item|Main Menu Dashboard@@labelDashboard"><mat-icon mat-list-icon>leaderboard</mat-icon>Dashboard</mat-list-option>
            <mat-list-option i18n="menu.item|Main Menu Users@@labelUsers"><mat-icon mat-list-icon>assignment_ind</mat-icon>Users</mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-drawer>


    <mat-drawer #drawerRight class="sidenav" mode="over" position="end" style="width: 700px">
        <router-outlet name="sideContent"></router-outlet>
    </mat-drawer>

    <div class="sidenav-content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

</mat-drawer-container>
```

Please note I have both side bars, the `drawerRight` is this one that has the aux routerOutlet.

Everything on the application happens on the `router-outlet` inside the `<div class="sidenav-content">`

My routes are lazy loaded, so the question is... is there a way for me to load children on the main router on that `sideContent` `router-outlet` ?

Comment: any stackblitz?

Comment: You should look into [named router outlets](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#description). You can then add the `outlet` property to your routes to specify the name of the router outlet that should render them.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the router config like.

```js
{
    path: "aux",
    outlet: 'sideContent',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/auxiliary/auxiliary.module').then(mod => mod.AuxiliaryModule),
}
```

Comment: Hey @JsNgian that makes sense, thank you! But in this case I would be loading everything that's part of the auxiliary module on the `sideContent` outlet. Let's say I have 3 routes on the auxiliary module. Is there a way I could load just one of them using the 'sideContent' and all the others using the main outlet?